# Are only certain VPC locations allowed for Transit Gateway?

Tags: cloud, vpc, transit-gateway

I can only provision a transit gateway in a certain set of locations on the provisioning page. Does that mean the VPC I want to connect has to be located in one of those locations?

Comment: Please, be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

No, by enabling "global routing" you can connect VPCs located in different MZRs (Multi Zone Regions) regardless of the set of locations you can provision your transit gateway in.

Some documentation that might help:

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/infrastructure/transit-gateway?topic=transit-gateway-helpful-tips
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/overview?topic=overview-locations#mzr-table